Preparing students to face challenges caused by artificial intelligence
Before the invention of computers, the main objective of teaching was to impart subject-related knowledge and train students in memorization. However, with the advent of computers and their vast and upgradable memory, memorization has become less critical. Now, we must adopt new approaches to prepare students to face the challenges posed by artificial intelligence.
Many discussions focus on how to teach students about artificial intelligence, a task best suited for experts in the field. However, a crucial aspect that needs attention is how to prepare students to face the challenges brought about by AI. For instance, fostering creativity may become more challenging when working with AI, as AI systems can also exhibit creative thinking. Do we need new approaches in preparing assessments?
To help students thrive in an AI-driven world, we must consider developing new skills that will support their ability to navigate and overcome AI-related challenges. What strategies would you suggest for achieving this goal in teaching mathematics?

P.S.
As an example in the arts, many artists have adopted graphic design apps to save time and enhance the appearance of their work. However, a few have pioneered unique creations that cannot be replicated by existing software. 
We need to remember while students are prohibited from using IT or AI in school math exams, in real life they have the freedom to utilize these technologies. We experienced somewhat similar situations when electronic calculators were introduced. There are exam papers containing questions in numerical forms for which students can use calculators and they are taught how to use calculators for various mathematical operations to answer those questions. There are some other maths papers where students are given questions in algebraic form which can not be answered using calculators.

It's worth noting that in the age of being able to quickly look stuff up, memorization of some things is still critical: it reduces the amount of working memory necessary for larger tasks.

@TomKern may be important but I don't think it is still critical. Not like in the beginning of the introduction of electronic calculators now there are exams students are allowed to use them. Wouldn't it be happened in the cases of computers and artificial intelligence in the future. Even now students are using AI to find answers for their assignments.

The skills that must be developed are critical thinking skills. There are no new skills. This never changes.

What should we do when a true believer asks a question composed mostly of articles of faith? To engage with the question, we would need to accept wrong or at least controversial axioms, and the poster's entire goal may be to just spread the faith instead of getting answers. That suggests it should be downvoted. On the other hand, it's somewhat useful to engage so that just in case the poster's goal really was to get expert opinions, they can try to rewrite the question without all the distractions. I downvoted this post. If you remove the 5-6 false statements from it, it would be answerable.

(1) The tradition on SE seems to be to hyphenate multiple-word tags. (2) We already have a [tag:technology-in-education] tag, which seems an appropriate one to replace the two new tags currently on this post.

@user52817 do you think critical thinking skills cannot be performed by AI. I think it's better to suggest which kind of critical thinking which is out of the reach of Artificial intelligence .

@ChrisCunningham could you please help me to find which statements are wrong? Memorization has become less critical or fostering creativity may become more challenging or any other thing?

Well, the printing press, and written language, has totally wrecked The Oral Tradition, since, nowadays, people can just look things up in books... :)

@JanakaRodrigo Whether AI has critical thinking skills is irrelevant. What is relevant is that humans using AI need to have critical thinking skills, as they always have needed and always will need.

Debating the core tenets of the current AI cult in a comment section is impossible, but the most egregious inaccuracies in your question are "AI systems can also exhibit creative thinking," "memorization has become less critical," "we must consider developing new skills that will support their ability to navigate and overcome AI-related challenges," and "Before the invention of computers, the main objective of teaching was to impart subject-related knowledge and train students in memorization."

@ChrisCunningham thanks for highlighting the issues which you think cannot be acceptable. Let me explain one by one,

@ChrisCunningham IBM says that "Artificial intelligence, or AI, is technology that enables computers and machines to simulate human intelligence and problem-solving capabilities." How can you disagree with the statement " AI can also exhibit creative thinking " because by the definition it has intelligence which enables it to be creative .

I guess I fell for the trap. I've voted to close the question; the poster is here to spread the good word of the AI and is not interested in improving the question.

@ChrisCunningham I have added examples regarding alternative skills which were introduced to face the challenges created by the invention of electronic calculators and computers . What I'm trying to do here is not promoting AI but researching on how we need to prepare ourselves for the future challenges in teaching mathematics .

Your question is of the form "Here is a list of opinions, all of which are true. Therefore, what should we do?" I count approximately five opinions, and I don't agree with a single one of them. I don't know how plausible most people find these opinions to be, but let's say for the sake of argument that the probability of agreement with one of them is 1/2. Then, assuming independent probabilities for the sake of estimation, the fraction of us who agree with the premise of your question might be 1/32.
To give some idea of the ways in which people might disagree with you, here are some of the ways in which I disagree.

Before the invention of computers, the main objective of teaching was to impart subject-related knowledge and train students in memorization.

Not true. This may characterize some subjects or some teachers or some educational systems. It doesn't correctly describe any teacher or subject I know.

However, with the advent of computers and their vast and upgradable memory, memorization has become less critical.

I disagree, basically for the reasons given by Tom Kern in comments.

Now, we must adopt new approaches to prepare students to face the challenges posed by artificial intelligence.

This seems like a lemma based on the previously listed hypotheses that I don't agree with, plus an additional implicit claim, which is that "artificial intelligence" is something that is "new" and has just happened "now." Artificial intelligence is a field where people have been working since the 1950's. They've been making progress in fits and starts. IMO generative AI such as ChatGPT is basically snake oil.

[...] a crucial aspect that needs attention is how to prepare students to face the challenges brought about by AI.

Actually, it isn't a math teacher's main job to train students in critical thinking so that they will be less vulnerable to snake oil. As with all teachers, it's probably true that most math teachers have decent critical thinking skills, and that most of them transmit some of those critical thinking skills to their students simply by their style of discourse and inquiry. If a math teacher wanted to do that in the specific case of AI, they might want to demonstrate that generative AI doesn't understand simple facts about math or logic, such as syllogisms or the fact that 5 is greater than 3.

"generative AI doesn't understand simple facts about math or logic, such as syllogisms or the fact that 5 is greater than 3." Though I agree with most of what you said, you are quite a bit behind the times with this sentence. Just try these claims of yours on Bing in Skype (which has been renamed "Copilot" recently) and you'll see that even it understands number ordering and elementary Aristotelian logic better than your average school kid. More advanced and specialized AI programs perform even better, in some cases much better.

Extremely sorry if the provided information was not enough for better understanding of the issue. I  have edited to add examples related to the electronic calculators and fine arts ( painting ) so that now you can get much clearer picture of the issue.

" Actually It isn't math teachers main job to train students in critical thinking " this statement is more than enough to understand the level of awareness one can have about mathematics education. You can agree with this if you are still in the most primary level of teaching and learning process which is considered as Factual teaching and learning process. Now we have passed the next level which is Conceptual teaching and learning process and come to the Contextual teaching and learning process.  Experienced maths educators know how important is developing critical thinking skills in  maths.

Let me explain me a very recent story about memorisation: I participated with a group of friends (adults and their adolescent children) to an event, and during the inscription we needed to enter the postal code of our hometown.
One of the adolescents, 13 years old, put his "smart"phone in front of his mouth and said "Postal code hometown", the "smart"phone answered "zero ...". The boy was about to write this down when one of the adults reacted that postal codes never start with zero, indicating that this was clearly some mistake (the adolescent boy clearly had no idea).
I later remembered another story of my niece's boys who, at the age of 6 and 8, were able to state very clearly "Familystreet 41 in Eastside!", so whenever they might get lost, they could inform people who they were and where they lived.
That 13-year old adolescent boy, does this mean that he's a retard?
Well, maybe. ... but maybe he's just a boy, being raised in an atmosphere where "memorisation is less critical", as you put it.
I hope, from this small story, that you understand that memorisation is very critical and always will be!
So, as you say: challenging children against the danger of artificial intelligence: ok, but never at the expense of simple memorisation.

As your examples indicate memorization can be critical in very rare cases not in general. Even in that sense AI might be not enough intelligent in answering particular issue but in general it is smarter than average human intelligence. Please note that I did not say memorization is not important. I  said it has become less important means comparing with the time when there was no readily available artificially stored memory . As educators we have to think what is the use of preparing students to face exams if exams are not conducted to test students ability to be successful in real life .

@JanakaRodrigo: you simply do not want to get it, do you? The example I've given is just a simple thing in life, as almost everything is something simple in life. Just have a walk, you see a bird flying away and you say "What was that? A crow? A Rook? Was it a jackdaw?" "Oh, no, you won't believe it, it was a raven!". "Really? Ravens? Here? That's a first!", and a child, having memorised nothing is just standing there, saying the words "Rook", "Crow", "Jackdaw" to his smartphone and having no clue what the whole fuzz is about. This is not the world people want for their children!

@JanakaRodrigo: in case you're not interested in birds, what about cars? Trees? Nationalities? Languages? ... Do you really want to fill the world with children who need their smartphone to understand every little thing their parents are talking about?

Why not I got it , by the way thanks for sharing your views. You may be correct for if you are not interested in the whole content because even if you to search something you need to know where you have to search

And there are internationally recognized maths exams which provides formulae sheets because examiners already realized that memorizing formulae is not much important when comparing with understanding . When you come to conceptual teaching and learning process what is more important is understanding rather than memorizing the facts.

@Janaka Rodrigo Why even bother posting things on a Q&A site if you are just going to argue against all the answers? You got three different professionals to spend time helping you and you totally failed to get anything from the experience.

@ChrisCunningham I think you too agree with me if I say arguing is the best way in a productive teaching and learning process because it helps for much better understanding. You can see how educators faced the challenge created by the electronic calculators and how artists are creative when overcoming the challenges of graphic design apps whivh can be downloaded to the  computers . You may have heard about Collatz Conjecture (1937) one of the greatest challenges still remains unsolved even using computers.

@ChrisCunningham If summarized, now we have to either just let our students to surrender to the artificial intelligence or develop new skills so that they can survive with human intelligence. If you study the history of mathematics education you can see how the new skills were added in the process of the teaching and learning . That is why we can not say there cannot be new skills . Thanks again for being in touch with this post.
